# Express $A^{2014}$ as a polynomial of least possible degree

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Given

$A=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
8 & 18 \\
-3 & -7  \end{array} \right)$

find the polynomial $p$ of least possible degree such that $p(A)=A^{2014}$.

The eigenvalues of $A$ are $-1$ and $2$. If I calculated correctly, $A^{2014}$ is $\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
-3 & -2^{2015} \\
1 & 2^{2014}  \end{array} \right)$.

Now, there should be two polynomials of degree $<2$ (because the multiplicities of the eigenvalues are $1$) such that $g_1(A)+2^{2014}g_2(A)=A^{2014}$. I'm unable to find those two so I'm guessing I made a mistake somewhere along the way.

How would I go about solving this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you know $A$ has two different eigenvalues $-1$ and $2$, diagonalize it to get $PAP^{-1} = \bigr({}^{-1}\,{}_2\bigl)$. (You don't need to calculate $P$; it is enough to know that it exists).

Then $PA^{2014}P^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2^{2014}\end{pmatrix}$, and all you need to do is to express that matrix as a linear combination of $PA^0P^{-1}=\bigr({}^1\,{}_1\bigl)$ and $PA^1P^{-1}=\bigr({}^{-1}\,{}_2\bigl)$. This gives you $a$ and $b$ such that
$$ aPA^1P^{-1} + bPA^0P^{-1} = PA^{2014}P^{-1} $$
Now cancel the $P$ and $P^{-1}$, and what is left is
$$ aA + bI = A^{2014} $$

Comment: Can you explain why I can just work with the diagonal form without caring about the base-switch matrices? Where do they come in? I mean, the problem specified this matrix. It didn't say anything about the linear map it represents. Will the polynomial I get doing what you say also work for the original matrix then?

Comment: Let $D$ be the diagonal matrix, and suppose $\alpha + \beta D = D^{2014}$. We know $A = PDP^{-1}$, this implies that $\alpha + \beta A = P(\alpha + \beta D)P^{-1} = P(D^{2014})P^{-1} = (PDP^{-1})^{2014} = A^{2014}$.

Comment: @LukaHorvat: I've extended the answer a bit.

Comment: And for maximal confusion, @Alex's $P$ is my $P^{-1}$. ;-)

Comment: Great answer. Thank you!